# Accessing Delphi Class Fields in 64 bit inline assembler

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, inline-assembly, delphi-xe4

I am trying to convert the Delphi TBits.GetBit to inline assembler for the 64 bit version. The VCL source looks like this:

```
function TBits.GetBit(Index: Integer): Boolean;
{$IFNDEF X86ASM}
var
  LRelInt: PInteger;
  LMask: Integer;
begin
  if (Index >= FSize) or (Index < 0) then
    Error;

  { Calculate the address of the related integer }
  LRelInt := FBits;
  Inc(LRelInt, Index div BitsPerInt);

  { Generate the mask }
  LMask := (1 shl (Index mod BitsPerInt));
  Result := (LRelInt^ and LMask) <> 0;
end;
{$ELSE X86ASM}
asm
    CMP     Index,[EAX].FSize
    JAE     TBits.Error
    MOV     EAX,[EAX].FBits
    BT      [EAX],Index
    SBB     EAX,EAX
    AND     EAX,1
end;
{$ENDIF X86ASM}
```

I started converting the 32 bit ASM code to 64 bit. After some searching, I found out that I need to change the EAX references to RAX for the 64 bit compiler. I ended up with this for the first line:

```
CMP     Index,[RAX].FSize
```

This compiles but gives an access violation when it runs. I tried a few combinations (e.g. `MOV     ECX,[RAX].FSize`) and get the same access violation when trying to access `[RAX].FSize`. When I look at the assembler that is generated by the Delphi compiler, it looks like my `[RAX].FSize` should be correct.

```
Unit72.pas.143: MOV     ECX,[RAX].FSize
00000000006963C0 8B8868060000     mov ecx,[rax+$00000668]
```

And the Delphi generated code:

```
Unit72.pas.131: if (Index >= FSize) or (Index < 0) then
00000000006963CF 488B4550         mov rax,[rbp+$50]
00000000006963D3 8B4D58           mov ecx,[rbp+$58]
00000000006963D6 3B8868060000     cmp ecx,[rax+$00000668]
00000000006963DC 7D06             jnl TForm72.GetBit + $24
00000000006963DE 837D5800         cmp dword ptr [rbp+$58],$00
00000000006963E2 7D09             jnl TForm72.GetBit + $2D
```

In both cases, the resulting assembler uses `[rax+$00000668]` for FSize. What is the correct way to access a class field in Delphi 64bit Assembler?

This may sound like a strange thing to optimize but the assembler for the 64bit pascal version doesn't appear to be very efficient. We call this routine a large number of times and it takes anything up to 5 times as long to execute depending on various factors.

Comment: Do you have a pascal version at hand?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Will put it in the question. Didn't want to put too much Delphi VCL source in the question. The 64 bit version is not the same.

Comment: It's VCL code is it? In that case I can find it.

Comment: Although $668 is a considerably higher offset than I would have expected, at least the compiler is consistent with using that value. However, your calculation of RAX differs from the compiler's. The compiler says that the `Self` pointer is stored at RBP+$50; it doesn't assume that the value is *already* in RAX. Likewise for the `Index` parameter at RBP+$58. This gets to the difference in calling conventions between x86 and x86_64.

Comment: @RobKennedy So all I need to do is add `MOV     RAX, Self` as the first line of the assembler to keep the code the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic problem is that you are using the wrong register. `Self` is passed as an implicit parameter, before all others. In the [x64 calling convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthk2dkh.aspx), that means it is passed in `RCX` and not `RAX`.

So `Self` is passed in `RCX` and `Index` is passed in `RDX`. Frankly, I think it's a mistake to use parameter names in inline assembler because they hide the fact that the parameter was passed in a register. If you happen to overwrite either `RDX`, then that changes the apparent value of `Index`.

So the `if` statement might be coded as

```
CMP     EDX,[RCX].FSize
JNL     TBits.Error
CMP     EDX,0
JL      TBits.Error
```

FWIW, this is a really simple function to implement and I don't believe that you will need to use any stack space. You have enough registers in x64 to be able to do this entirely using volatile registers.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I am surprised that the assembler generated by the Delphi compiler uses RAX in it's `CMP` instead of just using RCX.

Comment: You are looking at non-optimized code. Look at the asm produced when the optimizer is enabled. FWIW, I don't think the code is that bad, but it does perform two divides when one will suffice. I'd contemplate coding it in Pascal but using a `DivMod` function. Mine looks like this:

Comment: `procedure DivMod(Dividend, Divisor: Cardinal; out Quotient, Remainder: Cardinal);
{$IFDEF CPUX86}
asm
        PUSH  EBX
        MOV   EBX,EDX
        XOR   EDX,EDX
        DIV   EBX
        MOV   [ECX],EAX
        MOV   EBX,Remainder
        MOV   [EBX],EDX
        POP   EBX
end;
{$ELSE IF Defined(CPUX64)}
asm
        .NOFRAME
        MOV   EAX,ECX
        MOV   ECX,EDX
        XOR   EDX,EDX
        DIV   ECX
        MOV   [R8],EAX
        MOV   [R9],EDX
end;
{$ELSE}
  {$Message Error 'Unrecognised platform.'}
{$ENDIF}
`

Comment: In the optimized version they do `MOV RBX, RCX`, `MOV ESI, EDX` and then `CMP ESI, [RBX+$00000668]`. Perhaps they have improved that part in the later versions of Delphi. Our XE7 environment is not yet ready so I can't test on that yet.

Comment: The 64 bit compiler code gen hasn't changed much since release.

Comment: If you do write asm here, do yourself a favour and don't ever use a parameter name in asm. It's a horrid trap. Be explicit about how the params are travelling and what your register use is.

Comment: Will definitely heed that advice. It's been a while since I last worked in assembler (CHASM) so a lot has changed.

Comment: +1 especially for mentioning that it is often problematic to use parameter names if these are passed in registers, because it hides the fact that if the register is modified, accessing the parameter by name is unsafe. Use the register names instead.